# Thread class method run inner infinite loop

Tags: java

I have a small animation that I run with a thread. I pause and play the animation with two buttons. Here is the code in the run method.

```
public void run(){
    while(true){
      if(!exitFlag)
        randomBall();
    }
}
```

When I hit play for the first time, I start the thread and the animation runs, but when I hit pause and hit play again, the animation does not work. There is a weird thing happening, when I add the `System.out.println("here")`, the program acts fine.

```
public void run(){

    while(true){
      System.out.println("here");
      if(!exitFlag)
        randomBall();
    }
}
```

I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Here is my full code.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable{
  Button play;
  Button pause;
  int xpos;
  int ypos;
  boolean right;
  int randomYInc; //random x position increment
  int randomXInc; //random y position increment
  boolean top;
  boolean firstTime = true;
  boolean exitFlag = false;
  Thread th;
  Random rand;

  public void init(){
    play = new Button("play");
    pause = new Button("pause");
    MyHandler mh = new MyHandler();
    play.addActionListener(mh);
    pause.addActionListener(mh);
    add(play);
    add(pause);
    th = new Thread(this);
    xpos = 0;
    ypos = 50;
    right = true;
    rand = new Random();
    randomize();
  }

  public void randomize(){
    randomYInc = rand.nextInt((20 - 10) + 10) + 10;
    randomXInc = rand.nextInt((20 - 10) + 10) + 10;
  }

  private class MyHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      if(e.getSource() == play){
        if(firstTime){
          th.start();
          firstTime = false;
        }else{
          exitFlag = false;    
        }
      }else if(e.getSource() == pause){
        exitFlag = true;
        //try{th.wait();}catch(Exception ex){}
      }
    }

  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillOval(xpos, ypos, 30, 30);
  }

  public void run(){
    while(true){
      if(!exitFlag)
        randomBall();
    }
  }

  public void randomBall(){
    if(right && xpos < 270){ //did not hit right border yet
      if(xpos + randomXInc > 270){
        xpos = 270;
      }else{
        xpos += randomXInc;
      }

      if(ypos > 0 && top){ //did not hit top border yet
        if(ypos - randomYInc < 0){
          ypos = 0;
        }else{
          ypos -= randomYInc;
        }
      }

      if(ypos < 270 && !top){ //did not hit bottom border yet
        if(ypos + randomYInc > 270){
          ypos = 270;
        }else{
          ypos += randomYInc;
        }
      }
    }

    if(!right && xpos > 0){ //did not hit left border yet
      if(xpos - randomXInc < 0){
        xpos = 0;
      }else{
        xpos -= randomXInc;
      }

      if(ypos > 0 && top){ //did not hit top border yet
        if(ypos - randomYInc < 0){
          ypos = 0;
        }else{
          ypos -= randomYInc;
        }
      }

      if(ypos < 270 && !top){ //did not hit bottom border yet
        if(ypos + randomYInc > 270){
          ypos = 270;
        }else{
          ypos += randomYInc;
        }
      }
    }

    //conditions to change ball directions when it hits a border
    if(xpos <= 0){
      right = true;
      top = true;
      randomize();
    }else if(xpos >= 270){
      right = false;
      top = false;
      randomize();
    }else if(ypos <= 0){
      right = true;
      top = false;
      randomize();
    }else if(ypos >= 270){
      right = false;
      top = true;
      randomize();
    }

    repaint();

    try{
      Thread.sleep(80);
    }catch(Exception ex){}
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this design is that, when your exitFlag is true, you're getting an extremely short loop. As mentioned, you can fix the exitFlag so that the changes are visible, but you also might want to consider using a different mechanism for controlling the flow.

Comment: I tried stopping and resuming the animation with wait/notify . wait works just fine but notify gives an error.

Comment: Now i got it . Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show all yourcode, but I suppose that `exitFlag` is not marked as `volatile`.

to be short, without `volatile`, a thread can cache the value of a variable : it didn't see the new value setted by another thread without some kind of memory barrier.

Comment: It worked with volatile. Thank you very much. But may i ask  why he caches the value i only have one thread ?

Comment: @islamhany You are not using only one thread. Your code uses a thread, and Swing has another thread for handling GUI events.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) instead of `boolean` or `volatile boolean`

Answer (score 1):

If `exitFlag` is set to `false`, the loop boils down to: `while(true) {}`.

In other words, a so called spinloop: The CPU is 100% fully engaged and soon your laptop will fly out of the window, buoyed by the fans spinning at full power, flinging hot CPU exhaust out the exhaust ports. And then 5 minutes later your laptop crashes as it ran out of battery.

Don't spinloop.

Use `Thread.sleep` or `wait` or lock on something to let the CPU know it doesn't have to endlessly re-evaluate if `true` is still, you know, true. Or, just shut the thread down, and if the user hits start again, fire up a new one, probably simpler.

It also sounds like you may have synchronicity issues, as well as EDT issues, as well as event loop issues. You haven't pasted enough to know for sure.

- synchronicity: All threads have one evil coin. Evil in the sense that it is not going to hit heads/tails equally often, but instead, it'll land juuust to annoy you, maximizing the application of Murphy's law: That coin is flipped *every time* a field is written, from anywhere. If it's heads, the write is only done to a local copy, unique to just that thread, and no other threads will see your change. If it's tails, all other threads see it. Actually, it's even more evil: On reads the coin is flipped too. The name of the game is to make the VM never flip it. To do so, you must establish happens-before relationships. Entire books have been written on how to do it. Easiest way here, for you? Don't use a boolean. Use an instance of `AtomicBoolean`, and call `.set(true)` on it. (If you're interested in those books I mentioned, search for 'Java Memory Model').
- EDT: You can't do GUI stuff except on the Event Dispatch Thread. Which your newly fired up thread that runs `randomBall()` isn't. Use SwingUtilities.invokeLater, or swingworkers. It's not clear what UI framework you're using here, but most have this idea of 'GUI interaction *ONLY* on the EDT'. When you register event handlers, those run in the EDT, so the code that responds to 'this button was clicked' can just mess with the UI. But not a thread like you wrote here.
- Event looping: Generally you don't want threads to just keep chugging away and do the work as fast as the CPU will allow. That will starve out other threads and resources. Instead you establish some cadence, such as 60fps, and lock to it. In any case, of all the various threads and things that are running on the system, they either all should be rate limited, or all-but-one should be rate limited, and almost always you want the 'all are rate limited' part. That means `Thread.sleep` or `obj.wait` must be involved, or some framework that uses these things under the hood. Failure to do so causes said starvation which can easily explain what you are observing.

Comment: I am trying to stop and resume with wait/notify but it is not wotking.
`
  private class MyHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      if(e.getSource() == play){
        if(firstTime){
          th.start();
          firstTime = false;
        }else{
          th.notify();          
        }
      }else if(e.getSource() == pause){
        try{
          th.wait();
        }catch(Exception ex){}
      }
    }

  }
`

Answer (score 0):

One alternative, that avoids the spin loop is to use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

Then you can have

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, true);
```

The loop you've becomes.

```
while(true){
    sem.acquire();
    sem.release();
    randomBall();
}
```

Then in your action listeners, the stop method uses `sem.acquire()` which will make the while loop stop on acquire because there is only one permit. The start method would use `sem.release()`.